# Process Monitor equivalent for Raspberry

Tags: gratis, system-monitor, raspberry-pi, processes

I'm trying to write a shell script that does all sorts of configuration for me that I always do on a clean Raspbian image.

I find that I do many things with tools that use either some CLI menu or even some LXDE GUI configuration. It's hard to find out what those programs internally do and which config files they modify.

On Windows, I simply launch [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), do the stuff I like and look at the log which files were changed.

That tool

- shows exactly when (time stamp)
- which file (file name)
- was read or written (offset + number of bytes)
- and what the result of the operation was (success, file not found, ...)

In order to ask less questions on the Raspberry sister site and to spend less time on Google searching for problems that I could solve myself with an appropriate tool,

what is the ProcMon equivalent on Raspbian?

I have tried `top` and `htop`, but they focus on CPU only. My focus is on changed files and not CPU at all.

I don't want hashing of files, since this would require a lot of unnecessary overhead.